# Optional Union in type hint

Tags: python, python-3.7, type-hinting

In the type hint system, `Optional[T]` is said to be equivalent to `Union[T, None]`

Does this work for multiple type arguments? ie,

does `Optional[T,U]` break out to `Union[T,U,None]`, or do I need to write it as `Optional[Union[T,U]]`

Comment: Looks like `Optional[int, str]` gives a TypeError. Then again, `Union[None, int, str]` takes less space than what would be more readable, namely `Optional[Union[int, str]]`.

Comment: The biggest point here is that if you have a function whose argument can be one of a number of types OR nothing, you should probably be more explicit about what that type means. `Username = typing.TypeVar('Username', str); UserId = typing.TypeVar('UserId', int); UserIdentifier = typing.Union[Username, UserId]; Optional[UserIdentifier]` now that _means_ something

Comment: @AdamSmith I have an experimental use-case for doing mutations on a database entry. I wanted to denote three possible states for any field in a dataclass where the dataclass represents a mutation on the database entry. Say a field `t` is of type `T`. Either `t` is of `T`, therefore present and needs to be updated, `t` is `None` and should be ignored, or `t` is some marker class `type(Removal)` and needs to deleted. My fields then looked like `foo: Optional[Union[str, Removal]]`. Is there a cleaner way to reuse this typing format? Somehow get to say `foo: Modifiable[str]`

Comment: @flakes sure! Types are just objects like any others. `Modifiable = Optional[Union[str, Removal]]` is valid.

Comment: If you specifically want to be able to specify your modifiable type (e.g. `Modifiable[str]` or `Modifiable[int]`) then you can define it the same way Python internally defines `Union` or `Optional`. See https://gitlab.com/snippets/1836727

Comment: @AdamSmith Amazing! Thankyou!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may think of the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) library as a specification on how to declare certain types. If something is not defined in that specification then it's always better assume it to be an undefined behavior.

However in the particular case of Python and typing we have a kind-of-reference static type checker which is [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). So in order to get an answer for your question, or just programmatically check types, we may use it and see if it shows any warnings.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat check_optional.py 
import typing
def fn(x: typing.Optional[int, str]):
    pass
$ mypy check_optional.py 
check_optional.py:3: error: Optional[...] must have exactly one type argument
```

So no, `Optional[T, U]` is not possible in terms of mypy even if there's no trouble declaring it within the `typing` library.

Besides from "functional programming" perspective both `Optional` and `Union` are two distinct but well-known and well defined [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). A combination of two monads (`Union[T, U, None]`) is another monad, which however behaves differently than `Optional` and thus should not be named so. In other words, `Union[T, U, None]` is isomorphic to (=same as) `Optional[Union[T, U]]`, but not to a general `Optional[X]`.

Comment: Thanks for the mypy tutorial, I will use it in the future! In that last comment, did you mean to write that `Union[T, U, None]` is different to the optional?

Comment: Glad to hear! On the last paragraph I meant that `Union[T, U, None]` is isomorphic (=same) to `Optional[Union[T, U]]`, but not to a general `Optional[X]`.

Comment: PEP 604 makes it clear that that `None | x == Union[None, x] == Optional[x]`

Comment: So it does. Doesn't explain the issue, though